# Update statement in terms of performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

May be a discussion point, but would like to know which one is good in terms of performance.

- update by join
- update by where clause

basic data are:

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare @students Table
(
     Id                 Int Identity(1,1)
    ,Name               Varchar(100)
    ,CurrentRank        Int
)

Insert Into @students(Name) Values
 ('Alex')
,('Peter')
,('Mark')
,('Jhon')
,('Steven')

Declare @results Table
(
     RowId              Int Identity(1,1)
    ,Id                 Int
    ,Marks              Int
    ,ResultYear         Int
)

Insert Into @results(Id,Marks,ResultYear) Values
 (1,32,2015)
,(1,29,2015)
,(1,31,2015)
,(2,40,2015)
,(2,39,2015)
,(2,38,2015)
,(3,18,2015)
,(3,25,2015)
,(3,29,2015)
,(4,35,2015)
,(4,31,2015)
,(4,21,2015)
,(5,25,2015)
,(5,33,2015)
,(5,40,2015)

---- 1. update with join
Update  s
Set     s.CurrentRank = r.ResultRank
From    @students As s
        Join
        (
            Select   Id
                    ,Row_Number() Over(Order By Avg(r.Marks) Desc) As ResultRank
            From    @results As r
            Where   r.ResultYear = 2015
            Group By r.Id
        ) As r On s.Id = r.Id

---- 2. update by where
Update  @students
Set     CurrentRank = r.ResultRank
From    (
            Select   Id As StudentId
                    ,Row_Number() Over(Order By Avg(r.Marks) Desc) As ResultRank
            From    @results As r
            Where   r.ResultYear = 2015
            Group By r.Id
        ) As r
Where   Id = r.StudentId
```

- in above both update statement, would like to know, which one is
  good/best in terms of performance....
- considered there would be large amount of data, like records are in
  lacks in both, master and child table.

Comment: Measure them answering your own question.

Comment: execution plan is same of both, not able to judge which one is best while performance matters

Comment: i'd say it's update with where clause as it is straightforward unlike update clause will take more memory as it will process matched rows especially if your data is growing/big.

Comment: If you get the same execution plan (which I doubt) then the statemtents are identical.

Comment: run above whole query in your SSMS, you will find execution plan exactly the same.

Comment: How can I run the query when I don't have your database structure, indexes, statistics or data in the table?

Comment: If the execution plans are identical, then you've answered your own question: the performance is the same.